# What is the view of Islam on people that didn't had the opportunity to know Islam?

Tags: non-muslim

Over the centuries (and even today?) we'll find people that have the lack of opportunity to discover the truth (mostly members of pagan civilizations who have never made contact with Islam). I want to know what Islam sais about these.

Please provide `dalil` in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Allah doesn't punish anyone until they've heard the message.  This is very clear in the Quran in several ayat.  In Surah al-Isra' 17:15 =

> **And We never punish until We have sent a Messenger**

And the coversation with the people of hell as it comes in Surah az-Zumar 39:71 =

> **'And those who disbelieved will be driven to Hell in groups, till,
>   when they reach it, the gates thereof will be opened. And its keepers
>   will say, "Did not the Messengers come to you from yourselves, -
>   reciting to you the Verses of your Lord, and warning you of the
>   Meeting of this Day of yours?" They will say: "Yes, but the Word of
>   torment has been justified against the disbelievers!"'**

So no one will be punished or held accountable for something they had no control over.  This includes someone who hasn't heard of the message of Islam or even knew that there were Messengers from Allah.

There's a long hadith attributed to the Prophet Mohamed in *Musnad Ahmed* and it'll give a good idea on what will happen to people who did not hear the message =

al-Aswad b. Sari reported the Prophet said:

> "There are four will come to Allah on the Day of Resurrection: the
>   deaf man who never heard anything, the insane man, the very old man,
>   and the man who died during the fatrah (the time between Jesus and
>   Mohamed).  The deaf man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but I never
>   heard anything.’  The insane man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but the
>   children ran after me and threw stones at me.’  The very old man will
>   say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but I did not understand anything.’  The man
>   who died during the fatrah will say, ‘O Lord, no Messenger from You
>   came to me.’  He (Allah) will accept their promises of obedience, then
>   word will be sent to them to enter the Fire. By the One in Whose hand
>   is the soul of Mohamed, if they enter it, it will be cool and safe for
>   them."

And there was another hadith where it says Allah will test them on day of judgment.  But I couldn't find it right now.  However, I think this should give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is a fair judge.

Yes we do believe that if we disbelieve then we will end up in hell but some people know the truth (they know that there is only one worthy of worship and his name is Allah) but they decide not to believe maybe because they are ignorant or some other reason.

However there are people who are trying to find out the truth but they still don't understand and they may be confused. As this is not their fault and Allah knows what is in their heart they may be saved from hell fire. This could apply to mentally unstable people etc.

So if you have tried to find out the truth yet you have not been successful in hearing about Islam then it is not your fault and your will be treated fairly.

Allah has said he will not burden a soul beyond it can cope. Therefore if you actually try to find the truth you will never fail.

In conclusion if the message of Islam has not reached you then you are not at fault. However that does not mean they can do haraam things and do evil e.g. murder. They will still be judged for these actions as they should know this is not to be done.

Comment: Please provide references to your answer.